# sales order email is not working magento

Tags: email, magento

On my site sales order email is not working. when user registered than mail goes to the user but sale order email is not working. in email's template file template.php on line no 407 when I have change the if condition into 
if (!($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)) { than sales order email working and new user registration email stop working. 
in template.php code is :

```
  if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) { 
        /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
        $emailQueue = $this->getQueue();
        $emailQueue->setMessageBody($text);
        $emailQueue->setMessageParameters(array(
                'subject'           => $subject,
                'return_path_email' => $returnPathEmail,
                'is_plain'          => $this->isPlain(),
                'from_email'        => $this->getSenderEmail(),
                'from_name'         => $this->getSenderName(),
                'reply_to'          => $this->getMail()->getReplyTo(),
                'return_to'         => $this->getMail()->getReturnPath(),
            ))
            ->addRecipients($emails, $names, Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_TO)
            ->addRecipients($this->_bccEmails, array(), Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_BCC);
        $emailQueue->addMessageToQueue();

        return true;
    }
```

when I have changed the if condition like 
if (!($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)) {
than sales order mail working but new user registration stop working.
what can I do for sales order and new user registration emails ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.9.x store the order email in core_email_queue table to send the mail of order. You must to set the cron job in your server.
I think it will be work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have change if condition and its working for me. I have made changes in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php on line no 407
I have change the if condition
 if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) 
To 
 if (false/*$this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue*/)